# How do I reload Unicorn without killing the master process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, unicorn

I have a RubyOnRails project, and deployed it with Unicorn on nginx on an Ubuntu server.

I need to restart Unicorn if I change one of configuration files, but it makes my site shut down when I kill Unicorn's master process and start it again with `bundle exec`.

Is there any way to make Unicorn work with new files without killing the process and going down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my capistrano deploy.rb I have:

```
desc "Zero-downtime restart of Unicorn"
task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "kill -s USR2 unicorn_pid"
end
```

This is well documented in "[Lighting fast, zero-downtime deployments with git, capistrano, nginx and Unicorn](http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn)".

Comment: i've made some progress with your advice, thanks
but now i've got new errors. when i enter "cap restart" and enter my password, i've got following:

`** [out :: app_name] $rvm_path (/root/.rvm/) does not exist.  
*** [err :: app_name] /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell: line 57: rvm: command not found  
*** [err :: app_name] Error: RVM was unable to use 'ruby-1.9.2-p290'`
if i could understand results from google, i need to change my rvm_path var to "/usr/local/rvm/bin" (it is really existing dir), but i can't find it anywhere.

Comment: is restart a script you coded? If this is the case you can add an `rvm use 1.9.2`in your script to make it aware of the rvm version you need to use. Otherwise please mark the answer as correct and open a new one for the rvm issue. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Okay, i've fixed my rvm (there wasn't necessary gem) and now it seems that capistrano certainly does my command, but unicorn doesn't consider my changes in config files anyway. (for example, number of worker processes or database settings)

Comment: According to the docs, sending `USR2` will leave an old unicorn master process around.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers, including the accepted one, are bad.

http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html says send a `HUP` to the master process.

```rb
desc "Zero-downtime restart of Unicorn"
task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "kill -s HUP `cat tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`"
end
```

Comment: The question was not asking how to RELOAD (which is HUP) but how to RESTART gracefully which is already USR2

Comment: I think OP don't care to reload or restart, just want to update with new configs.